# How to dump a dataset or datatable to MS Access in winforms 2.0 using c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, ms-access-2007

I have windows application, i want to dump a dataset or datatable to a local DB which is MS Access.

Can any one have any suggestion over it ?

Answer (score 1):

Is the DB already created? If so just use a OleDB DataAdapter.

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Pathname");
con.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new DataAdapter(SQL command, conn);
da.Update(dataset);
con.Close();
```

Comment: not working...actualy i want to get entire datatable or dataset to access db atonce, because it may have more then 10000 records....